# Let $|A|=|B|=|C|=n$ be three finite sets of integers. Find $\min |\{ab+c \mid a \in A, b \in B, c \in C\}|$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics, integers

For a triple of sets of integers $A,B,C$ with $|A|=|B|=|C|=n$,  we can compute the set $S_{A,B,C} = \{ab+c \mid a \in A, b \in B, c \in C\}$.  I am interested in the minimum sized $S_{A,B,C}$ when taken over all possible such triples of sets.

It is clear that it can be no bigger than $n^3$ and in fact one can show that it the minimum size is $\mathcal O(n^2)$. This is because $A=B=\{2^i | 0 \le i < n\}$ gives us $2n$ distinct values of $ab$ and we therefore get at most $2n^2$ distinct values once we include the set $C$.

Clearly the answer is also at least $n$, since one can pick a fixed $a$ and $b$, and argue that $\{ab+c \mid c \in C\}$ has exactly $n$ elements.

However, I have no idea beyond that.

Link to [original question](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38218535#38218535), and link to [approval of original author](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38218881#38218881).

> What is the smallest sized set $S_{A,B,C}$ one can get for a fixed set
>   size $n$? That is, what is $\min_{A,B,C} |S_{A,B,C}|$? Is it possible to get anything smaller than $\mathcal O(n^2)$ asymptotically?

Comment: I don't agree with your edit. This is a very specific case chosen on purpose, but A and B won't generally be so similar.

Comment: @Evargalo To be clear, we are choosing $A$, $B$, and $C$ to generate the minimum number of elements of the set.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry. Otherwise we can easily maximize it to reach $n^3$ (let $B=C=\{1,..,n\}$ and $A=\{(n+1)^k, k\in B\}$)